# How to calculate x and y of a circle for CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, math

I am not a Math guy. I am just a CSS guy. I am trying to calculate the position of an object using javascript. Think of an unordered list.

```
<ul>
  <li>
   <a href="#">Parent 1</a>
   <ul>
      <li>Service 1</li>
      <li>Service 2</li>
      <li>Service 3</li>
      <li>Service 4</li>
      <li>Service 5</li>
      ...
   </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I want to have all the services around the parent like a bubble. I need to be able to calculate the position of each services.
I am planning to have parent position to "relative" and services "absolute". I would like to use javascript to calculate no of services and the position using pi or sin or whatever the Math guys use. I am zero on Math.

What i have got so far is
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oaidr which is not reusable function.

Comment: And where is the circle?

Comment: This is one of those times where a picture of what you are going for would be really helpful.

Comment: I have done something on codepen. But i would like to write a function so that i can have nested services. Kind of tree structure. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oaidr

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want "service 1" to appear at the top, and then the rest to follow clockwise (i.e. just like the hands on a clock) then the basic math you need is this:

First - figure out how many elements there are:

```
var count = $('#myList > li').length;
```

Then each element `i` from `0 .. count - 1` would need to be positioned at an angle theta:

```
var theta = 2 * Math.PI * (i / count);  2*pi radians split into "count" sections
```

giving coordinates:

```
var left = horizontalCenter + radius * Math.sin(theta);
var top  = verticalCenter   - radius * Math.cos(theta);
```

Do bear in mind that this just sets the top-left corner of the element - further tweaking may be required to calculate the position of the center of the element.

NB: this is different to the standard cartesian convention of angles being calculated anti-clockwise relative to the positive X axis, hence why the `sin` and `cos` terms are swapped and the `top` having a subtraction instead of an addition to account for the way Y coordinates start at zero at the top of the page.

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/ah1k1mo3/

Comment: That's it. This is what i need, this is what i need. You are a math guru.